# drupal views: how to add generate pdf link in views

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, pdf-generation, drupal-views

I have to add generate pdf links in the view how to that...
When the user clicks on the generate pdf links pdf should be generated which contains the content information of that node...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you need is to install the print module and enable the printing.  You'll then notice a link structure for Print.  I think its different in 5.x than it is in 6.x but basically you'll end up with a link like http://example.com/print/pdf/530 (or similar) to print node 530.  So for your Views 2.x you can add a field that outputs a link, which you can then use print/pdf/[nid].  To get nid, I believe you'll need to add a "relationship" to the View which stores the nid.

Answer (score 2):

Place this code in header or footer of views as php code:

```
<?php
print print_pdf_insert_link(); 
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You may forget VBO and add the NID field and make it a link to printpdf/[Nid] (target _blank).

You can even replace the output by the PDF icon, using an img html tag, like this:

```
<img src="/modules/acquia/print/icons/pdf_icon.gif">
```

or any other path to a PDF mimetype icon.

Answer (score 2):

I know we're 2 years later but the [Views PDF](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_pdf) module is perfect for this. Some details about it (from its project page):

> With this module you can output a view as a PDF document. Each field of the view can be placed on the PDF page directly in the administration interface. Therefore a new display called "PDF" is added.

Answer (score 1):

If you use "Row Style: Node" in your view and you have the pdf option of the print module on then the pdf link will appear in your view. If the default Node view doesn't work for you, you can tweak it using the Content Template module ([http://drupal.org/project/contemplate)](http://drupal.org/project/contemplate).

Beyond that I think it would take a custom module.

Answer (score 0):

To create a printable PDF from a node, I would check out the [Print](https://www.drupal.org/project/print) module. Some details about it (from its project page):

> This module allows you to generate the following printer-friendly versions of any node:
>
> - Printer-friendly version (webpage format) (at www.example.com/print/nid)
> - PDF version (at www.example.com/printpdf/nid)
> - EPUB version (at www.example.com/printepub/nid)
> - Send by email (at www.example.com/printmail/nid)
>
> where nid is the node id of content to render.

Comment: that is to generate from node i need to generate from view ..
how we gonna do that....