# drupal Generate a PDF catalog from a bunch of nodes

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-views, drupal-modules, drupal-5

i have to generate the pdf file with bunch of nodes, i can generate pdf files with print pdf modules

but i want to generate the 
i m using views bulk operations i want to generate the pdf files with all the selected nodes.
any one knows how to do this stuff

Comment: possible duplicate of [drupal views: how to add generate pdf link in views](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2112532/drupal-views-how-to-add-generate-pdf-link-in-views)

Answer (score 0):

i have got the answer generate the view in node style and name it as printnodes
now call this function /printpdf/printnodes
u will get the list of nodes in one pdf file

change the view style as u want and u can even pass the arguments to the veiw.....